# How to present an UIImagePickerController in a Popover with iOS 9 and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to present the photo library, in a popover, on an iPad with iOS 9 beta 4 and Swift. The preferred way is through a popover, but `UIPopoverController` is now deprecated. Apparently it's now done through `UIViewController`, but there is no documentation, or sample code out there that I could find. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

The above answer is almost correct except that the anchor in the `popoverPresentationController` must be set prior to calling `presentViewController()`:

```
let myPicker = UIImagePickerController()
myPicker.delegate = self
myPicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
myPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

let ppc = myPicker.popoverPresentationController
ppc?.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
ppc?.permittedArrowDirection = .Any

presentViewController(myPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Per Apple documentation:

Configuring the popover presentation controller after calling presentViewController:animated:completion: might seem counter-intuitive but UIKit does not create a presentation controller until after you initiate a presentation. In addition, UIKit must wait until the next update cycle to display new content onscreen anyway. That delay gives you time to configure the presentation controller for your popover.

Comment: Instead of setting a barButtonItem it's also possible to set a sourceView from which the popover will be presented. This is helpful if you don't have a barButton from which the popover should be presented.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't entered into delegation and handling of the image picker responses here, the purpose of this post has simply been to consider the use of UIImagePickerController without resorting to deprecated classes and methods.

```
let myPicker = UIImagePickerController()
myPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

myPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

self.presentViewController(myPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

let popper = myPicker.popoverPresentationController
// returns a UIPopoverPresentationController
popper?.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
```

please Correct if needed

Comment: How to do in objective-c?

Answer (score -1):

simply added imagePicker.delegate = self in the function that calls up the imagepicker